# Proper map iff for every sequence $\{x_{n}\} \to \partial D_{1}$, also $\{f(x_{n})\} \to \partial D_{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, compactness

We have a proper map $f$, this means a continous map $f \colon X \to Y$, so that for every $K \subset Y$ compact, also $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact.

Question: Let $D_{1} \subset R^n$ and $D_{2} \subset R^m$ be bounded open sets (domains). Then the map $f \colon D_{1} \to D_{2}$ is proper if and only if for every sequence $\{x_{n}\} \subset D_{1}$ with the property $\{x_{n}\} \to \partial D_{1}$, we have $\{f(x_{n})\} \to \partial D_{2}$.

Comment: What does it mean to say $x_n\to\partial D$? The sequence tends to a point on the boundary or the distance tends to zero?

Comment: $lim_{j \to \infty} dist(z_{j}, \partial D_{1}) =0$ and $lim_{j \to \infty} dist(f(z_{j}), \partial D_{2}) =0$.\\
But are those to things (sequence tends to a point on the boundary or distance tends to zero) different ?

Comment: The former implies the latter but not the other way round.

Comment: So this means that if $lim_{j \to \infty} dist(z_{j}, \partial D_{1})=0$, then $lim_{j \to \infty} x_{j}$ can lie either on $\partial D_{1}$ or on $D_{1}$, but very very close to $\partial D_{1}$ ? But the proof of the implication $\Rightarrow$ I gave is still correct, is it ? Since if $f^{-1}(K)$ woul be compact, it would let out some points on $\D_{1}$ infinitely close to $\partial D_{1}$, thus also the limit point ?

Comment: not exactly. What I mean: if the sequence tends to a point then the distance must tend to zero, but on the other hand, if the distance tends to zero, the sequence may fail to converge.

Comment: Yeah, but $\overline{D_{1}}$ is comapct, so the sequence converges to at least one point ?

Comment: there is at least one subsequence that tends to one point on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it in one direction.
Lets say there exists a sequence $\{x_{n}\} \to \partial D_{1}$, such that $\{f(x_{n})\}$ does not converge to $\partial D_{2}$. Then $lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_{n}) = y \in D_{2}$. Lets take a compact $K$ around $y$ which contains the convergent sequence $\{f(x_{n})\}$. In its preimage $f^{-1}(K)$, there is the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ which has no limits inside $f^{-1}(K)$, therefore $f^{-1}(K)$ is not compact. So we have found a compact $K$, whose preimage $f^{-1}(K)$ is not compact and so $f$ is not a proper map.

Any ideas for the other direction ?